# PHP & Smarty - Submit form to self within Ajax Tab

Tags: php, ajax, smarty

I have an ajax tab with a form inside it, with url http://example.com/tabs.php#pg=3, and I'm trying to submit the form to this tab using `{$smarty.server.REQUEST_URI}`, and although this does in fact submit the form to the correct .php file (used by the ajax tab), it is no longer contained within an ajax tab (I end up at http://example.com/formhandle.php).

Does anyone have an idea of how to submit the form to itself contained within the ajax tab? I've tried submitting to the URL of the specific tab (http://example.com/tabs.php#pg=3), however if I do this, the form post isn't actually handled. I'm stuck on this one.

Comment: What does it mean `form post isn't actually handled`? You should put some code otherwise we can only guess what you are doing

Answer (score 0):

Your code within formhandle.php would need to be moved to or [included](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php) in tabs.php